# Is it possible to use an external SDK or data fetching library like Kitsu with RTK Query/Redux Toolkit?

Tags: redux, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

According to the [RTK Query documentation](https://deploy-preview-1079--redux-starter-kit-docs.netlify.app/rtk-query/usage/queries), I can create queries like the following:

```js
export const projectsApi = createApi({
  reducerPath: 'projects',
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
    baseUrl: "https://some-site.com/api/",
    prepareHeaders: (headers) => {
      headers.set('Authorization', `Bearer ${accessToken}`);

      return headers;
    },
  }),
  tagTypes: ['Project'],
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    fetchProjects: builder.query<Project[], void>({
      query: () => ({ url: `projects` }),
    }),
  }),
});
```

The above works as expected. However, if want to use an external library like [Kitsu](https://github.com/wopian/kitsu/) to fetch and transform the data, I get the following error:

[image: RTK query error]

Here is my updated code while using with Kitsu:

```js
export const projectsApi = createApi({
  reducerPath: 'projects',
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
    baseUrl: "https://some-site.com/api/",
  }),
  tagTypes: ['Project'],
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    fetchProjects: builder.query<Project[], void>({
      query: api.get('projects'),
    }),
  }),
});
```

Here is the code for the **api** function:

```js
const kitsu = (accessToken: string) => {
  return new Kitsu({
    baseURL: "https://some-site.com/api/",
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
    },
  });
};

const api = kitsu("ey....");
```

Is it possible to override the **baseQuery** function of RTK Query/Redux Toolkit with the one that Kitsu or any 3rd party package provides?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there's a couple options here:

- You can create your own function that implements the "base query" behavior and use that as the `baseQuery` option of the API slice
- You can override individual endpoints by giving them a `queryFn` option, which can be any async function that fetches some data and returns it in the right format.

See the ["Customizing Queries" page in the RTK Query preview docs](https://deploy-preview-1016--redux-starter-kit-docs.netlify.app/rtk-query/usage/customizing-queries) for instructions on how to do both of those.

Comment: Thank you. This helps a lot. However, since there isn't any `baseQuery`, I am defining `baseQuery` as `baseQuery: () => data: {}`. Is this fine?

Comment: RTK-Query exports `fakeBaseQuery` for that purpose, but your implementation is equally fine ;)